# asp.net child menu items dissappear on android devices

Tags: android, asp.net, menu

In 2 seperate web applications, one using asp.net 3.5 with vs2008 and 4.0 with vs2010, the child menu items of an asp.net menu dissappear only on android browser.  When the main menu item is clicked the children flash for a split second then dissappear.

Edited version of menu is as follows:

```
<asp:Menu ID="MainMenuEmp" runat="server" CssClass="menuASP" Orientation="Horizontal" DynamicHorizontalOffset="0" 
                        StaticDisplayLevels="1" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" DynamicVerticalOffset="1" visible="false" 
                        > 
                       <StaticMenuitemStyle CssClass="menuitemASPStatic" /> 
                       <StaticHoverStyle    CssClass="menuASPStaticHover" />
                       <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="menuASPStaticHover" /> 
                       <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="menuASPDynamicMenuStyle" />
                       <DynamicMenuitemStyle CssClass="menuitemASPDynamic" /> 
                       <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="menuASPDynamicHover" />
                       <DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="menuASPDynamicHover" /> 
                       <Items>
                           <asp:MenuItem Text="HISTORY" Value="@" navigateurl="~/clientpages/jobhistory.aspx" />
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="NEW ORDER" Value="@" navigateurl="~/clientpages/newjob.aspx"  />
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="CLIENT INFO" Value="@" navigateurl="~/clientpages/clientinfo.aspx"  />
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="MGMT" Value="@"  Selectable="false"  >
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Inspections" Value="@" navigateurl="~/clientpages/MgrInspection.aspx" />
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Tasks" Value="@" navigateurl="~/clientpages/MgrInspectionStatus.aspx"/>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Last Vehicle Inspection" Value="@" navigateurl="~/clientpages/MgrInspectionVehicle.aspx"/>
                            </asp:MenuItem >
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="JOB MGMT" Value="@" navigateurl="~/clientpages/jobdailyview.aspx"/>
                       </Items>
                    </asp:Menu>
```

partial css is as follows: (z-index is needed to get sub menu's to show on other browsers).

```
.menuASPDynamicMenuStyle
{
    z-index: 999; /*padding: 4px 0 3px 0;*/
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 1px; 
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

Menu is on master page with toolscriptmanager on page.

The following code is in init event of masterpage:

```
If Request.ServerVariables("http_user_agent").IndexOf("Safari", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) <> -1 Then
                Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel"
            End If
```

This was necessary to get child menu's to show on other browsers as well.  I tried:

```
page.clienttarget = "uplevel"
```

without the condition, but, this did not work.

I have also tried adding an android browser file, but, this did not work.

I have scoured the web for a few days.  There a few similar questions, but, no answers.  Has anyone had same problem?  The menu works fine in ie, chrome, ff, safari, ipad, but, not on android mobile devices and not on android tablets.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hover on an Android but my asp menu works if I hold down on the parent menu. Sadly I also get the browser menu when I hold down on it. You will have to design a menu that opens the child items with a single click. This cannot be done with the asp menu.

Answer (score 0):

menus are not disappearing but the page is posting back..

just set navigateUrl property to 'javascript:return false'

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this.

Either do

```
document.body.setAttribute('onclick', 'setTimeout(function () { }, 0);');
```

in a startup script

or let the body tag look like this

```
<body onclick="setTimeout(function () { }, 0);">
```

Then it works on Android. I haven't tested on other iPhone or so.

(I have also tried some more conventional ways of adding this dummy script, but it did not work.)